# Python splitting list by whitespace

Tags: python

I have a textfile with numbers in the following manner "12345679010111213"
I have constructed a script that reads the fille, appends the values to the list, using a variable called "numbersoflist" `list1.append(numbersoflist)`

But when I call the `list1.split('')` it still prints out the values as they appear in the textfile, without whitespaces. My goal is to have them look like "1 2 3 4 5 6 ..."

Comment: Can you show your code? Given your description, I'd expect an `AttributeError`... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = '12345679010111213'
>>> list(s)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3']
>>> ' '.join(list(s))
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 0 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 3'
>>> ' '.join(s) # works since str is also an iterable
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 0 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 3'
```

Comment: When splitting, do I always have to join them back together?

Comment: @pythonz you don't even want to split then... there's nothing to split on in this case :)

Comment: Right, so If the list looked like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" I would use split on ',' to get: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7? and when list is 1234567 I do join on ' ' to add a seperating whitespace? @jon clements

Comment: @pythonz exactly - you'd probably use `.replace(',', ' ')` in the first case if you wanted them space separated, but you're right in the second case

Comment: Great! Thank you! Solved it for me!